# Надо ли писать для каждого действия свой маршрут?

Tags: laravel

Недавно начал работать с Laravel, до этого работал с Codigniter.
Для каждого экшна надо писать свой маршрут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном да, однако существуют:

### [RESTful-контроллеры ресурсов](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers#%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81)

Контроллеры ресурсов упрощают построение RESTful-контроллеров, работающих с ресурсами. Например, вы можете создать контроллер, обрабатывающий фотографии, хранимые вашим приложением. Вы можете быстро создать такой контроллер с помощью Artisan-команды `make:controller`:

```
php artisan make:controller PhotoController
```

Теперь мы можем зарегистрировать маршрут контроллера ресурса:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

Этот единственный вызов создаёт множество маршрутов для обработки различных RESTful-действий на ресурсе `photo`. Сам сгенерированный контроллер уже имеет методы-заглушки для каждого из этих *действий* с комментариями о том, какие типы запросов они обрабатывают.

***Действия*, обрабатываемые контроллером ресурсов**

```
| Тип           | Путь                  | Действие  | Имя маршрута      |
|-----------    |---------------------  |---------- |---------------    |
| GET           | /photo                | index     | photo.index       |
| GET           | /photo/create         | create    | photo.create      |
| POST          | /photo                | store     | photo.store       |
| GET           | /photo/{photo}        | show      | photo.show        |
| GET           | /photo/{photo}/edit   | edit      | photo.edit        |
| PUT/PATCH     | /photo/{photo}        | update    | photo.update      |
| DELETE        | /photo/{photo}        | destroy   | photo.destroy     |
```

---

### [Неявные контроллеры](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Laravel позволяет вам легко создавать единый маршрут для обработки всех *действий* контроллера. Для начала зарегистрируйте маршрут методом `Route::controller()`:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

Метод `controller()` принимает два аргумента. Первый — корневой [URI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=URI) (путь), который обрабатывает данный контроллер, а второй — имя класса самого контроллера. После регистрации просто добавьте методы в этот класс с префиксом в виде типа HTTP-запроса (*HTTP verb*), который они обрабатывают:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

  public function getIndex()
  {
    //
  }

  public function postProfile()
  {
    //
  }

  public function anyLogin()
  {
    //
  }

}
```

Методы `index` обрабатывают корневой URI контроллера — в нашем случае это `users`.

Если имя действия вашего контроллера состоит из нескольких слов вы можете обратиться к нему по URI, используя синтаксис с дефисами (-). Например, следующее действие в нашем классе `UserController` будет доступно по адресу `users/admin-profile`:

```
public function getAdminProfile() {}
```

**Назначение имён маршрутов**

Если вы хотите *назвать* некоторые маршруты в контроллере, вы можете передать третий аргумент в метод `controller`:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController', [
  'anyLogin' => 'user.login',
]);
```

---

А вообще, в полной мере на ваш вопрос ответит только [документация](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/routing).

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить еще упоминание про [Неявные контроллеры](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers#неявные)

Comment: @xEdelweiss, я обновил ответ